# Python - If more inputs return error (How to do)

Tags: python, calculator

Beginner programmer, I am making a function which does square root calculations, 
Here is my function:

The input is a tuple actually which i want to be like this
`("sqrt",number)`

```
def calculator(input):
    if input[0] == "sqrt":
        if input[1]<0 :                      # Error for negative input of number
            return "No square root for negative numbers"
        else:
            ans = (input[1])**(0.5)
            return ans
```

But here comes the problem, I also want, if a user inserts more than one input i.e `("sqrt",number1,number2)` then it returns an error say `"Please only one input"`

Here is what I thought

```
if input[1] == anything at all:
      return "Please only one input"
```

the part `anything at all` what function should i put?? poorly i tried

```
 if input[1] != ""
```

Of course, I got a huge error screaming at me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in `len()` function to make sure the length is not greater than 2:

```
def calculator(input):
    if len(input) > 2:
        print "Please only one input"
        break
    else:
        #Do the rest of your code
        if input[0] == "sqrt":
            if input[1]<0 :                      # Error for negative input of number
                return "No square root for negative numbers"
            else:
                ans = (input[1])**(0.5)
                return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ..

```
def calculator(*args):
    input=args[0]
    num1 = args[1]
    numberOfArguments = len(args)
    print input
    print num1
    print len(args)
    if numberOfArguments > 2 :
        print "Please only one input"
    else:
        if input == "sqrt":
            print "we will perform sqrt now"
            if num1 < 0 :                      # Error for negative input of number
                return "No square root for negative numbers"
            else:
                ans = (num1)**(0.5)
                print "square root result is ",ans
                return ans
```

## Call with more than 1 input

```
calculator("sqrt",25,2)
```

## Call with 1 input

```
calculator("sqrt",25)
```

Hope this helps :)